# Better way to communicate between TCP Client and Server

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a commandsystem to communicate between my TCP Server and Client (Java). I can send specific commands to my Client, if the Client received a command, it will execute something.

Basically, thats working. But sometimes I have to send the command + extra informations. The problem is: The informations will sometimes be sent too fast. So some information will get lost / mixed up and my Client cant execute the request properly.
The solution for me was to use `Thread.sleep()`, but this isn't clean nor efficent. Because there is still a risk that the information will not be received properly.

My Server:

```java
public void sendCommand(Socket socket) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    writeMsg("CMD_POPUP", socket);
    Thread.sleep(150);
    writeMsg("foo", socket);
    Thread.sleep(150);
    writeMsg("bar", socket);
    Thread.sleep(150);
    writeMsg("baz", socket);
}

public void writeMsg(String message, Socket socket) throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    out.writeUTF(message);
}
```

My Client:

```java
public void interpreteCommand(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    while (true) {
        switch (readMsg(socket)) {
            case "CMD_POPUP":
                System.out.println(readMsg(socket)); 
                System.out.println(readMsg(socket)); //Sometimes it would be 'bar' but also sometimes it would be 'baz'
                System.out.println(readMsg(socket)); //Sometimes it would be 'baz' but also sometimes it would be nothing
                break;
        }
    }
}

public String readMsg(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
    return in.readUTF();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I'm not a java programmer. However tcp connections work the same way in other programming languages.

TCP Connections are stream-based, meaning there is no start or end of a message. The only thing TCP guarantees is that the data is arriving in the right order.

If you send "CMD_POPUP" and "foo" immediately after each other, you don't know if you will receive "CMD_POPUP", "CMD_POPUPfoo", "CMD_PO" etc. on the other side. Because you are waiting a specific amount of time between each send, the data usually does arrive one after each other. But that is not guaranteed and I would also consider this a not very clean way of doing it.

The easiest way to get around this is to send a start character in the beginning, separator characters between the parameters and a end-character after each message.
e.g. "#CMD_POPUP%foo%bar$" or sth like that. This way, you can write everything you receive to a buffer until you receive the end of a message, and then process it.

Comment: _"The only thing TCP guarantees is that the data is arriving in the right order."_ - actually, a little bit more than that: It arrives _at all and_ all parts of it in the correct order.

Comment: _"The easiest way to get around this is to send a start character in the beginning..."_ = implement some kind of application protocol.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you don't need `Thread.sleep` instead you can pass extra information appended with the command itself like `writeMsg("foo;extrainformation", socket);` and on the other side split this string where first part is command. 
 
 
Otherwise, Instead of passing the `string` you can pass entire `object` or `json` structure for better implementation.